# "Needs Improvement" reason is missing from flag choices

Tags: discussion, flags

I was attempting to flag a clearly off-topic question, but the set of flags did not include "needs improvement"

There were only a few choices, much less than normal.  Is this a new simplified set of choices?

I understand that it requires a judgment call for borderline questions like using development-adjacent tools such as network sniffers.  However, many questions are clearly off-topic: asking for legal advice, asking how to use (random productivity app), asking for help with OS behavior issues, etc.

I searched but didn't find any information.  Is there a blog or announcement that explains this change?

Comment: Needs Improvement --> Community Specific Reason --> Not About Programming or Software Development?

Comment: @Warcupine - thanks but see edit, for one question I tried to flag, most of the options including Needs Improvement were missing.   The voices in my head tell me I'm not imagining things.

Comment: Was the question already closed? (Sometimes the close votes sneak in really quick.) You would only have Spam, Abusive, and Needs Moderator Attention in that case.

Comment: @Laurel - yes, I think that was it.  The question was no-question off topic so it was probably closed just as I clicked flag and I missed the closed box in the question wording.  I'll leave this up instead of deleting in case anyone else is confused by this behavior.

Comment: Fair point.  @Laurel  - it's your answer so I'll only add it if you don't want to take the time.  Once one of us does it I'll accept and then edit the question.

Comment: @pppery - maybe: the answer is the same, but the question keywords are different enough that searching on "needs improvement" won't find that question, and searching on "flags" will return too many answers.  That's fine for me, but if this is deleted others who are trying to find "needs improvement" answers won't find that question + answer.

Comment: The entire point of duplicate closure is to serve as a signpost, not to enable deletion.

Comment: @pppery - thanks,, I don't have close or delete powers so I didn't realize closed questions are just closed not deleted.  Closing as a duplicate linked to the other question makes sense then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is already closed, you'll only have these options:

[image: Spam, Abusive, and Needs Moderator Attention]

Refresh the page!

Comment: Changed September 2023:  I'm now seeing a popup "This question is now closed - please refresh the page for updated status." instead of the confusing partial list of flags.  Much better.